# 403 Forbidden error when I want to add index.html docker nginx in windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, nginx, cmd

I am starting with docker by following a little tutorial. All I want is to add a simple custom index.html when accessing a nginx container with docker on windows 10.

In a directory created on my computer, site-content, I have my index.html file stored and I launch from the command line (windows CMD): `docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:80 --name web -v //site-content:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx`

But when accessing the browser http://localhost:8080/ the message is: *403 Forbidden* and not the content of index.html

Someone can tell me what I am doing wrong or what is my mistake

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`-it` and `-d` are seldom used together. `-it` is when you want the container to be attached to the shell and `-d` is for when you want to run the container detached.

`//site-content` is a notation I haven't seen before. When doing bind mounts of directories, the host path has to be absolute. So if your index.html is in the current directory, you can do

```
docker run --rm -d -p 8080:80 --name web -v %cd%:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

`%cd%` will be replaced with the full path of the current directory.